# can anyone explain what is the use of enabling activity trace in MQ?

Tags: ibm-mq, mq

what kind of information does it gives after enabling activity trace on MQ? Does it have any impact on the performance?

Answer (score 1):

Chapter [Application activity trace](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.2.0/com.ibm.mq.mon.doc/q037520_.html) explains it like this:

> Application activity trace produces detailed information about the behavior of applications connected to a queue manager. It traces the behavior of an application and provides a detailed view of the parameters used by an application as it interacts with IBM® MQ resources. It also shows the sequence of MQI calls issued by an application.

Chapter [Tuning the performance impact of application activity trace](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.2.0/com.ibm.mq.mon.doc/q037580_.html) explains it like this:

> Enabling application activity trace can incur a performance penalty. This can be reduced by only tracing the applications that you need, by increasing the number of applications draining the queue, and by tuning ActivityInterval, ActivityCount and TraceLevel in mqat.ini.

I really recommend to consult the Knowledge Center to read about the features of IBM MQ.

Answer (score 0):

Activity Trace is a feature of IBM MQ that allows you to discover exactly
what the applications connected to your queue manager are doing. You can see the
object names that they open and the options they use on the various verbs they
call. Feature is only available on the Distributed platforms.

Answer (score 0):

There's a presentation on this here
https://www.mqtechconference.com/sessions_v2018/MQTC_v2018_ActivityTrace.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I used it and some python to produce a picture of what queues were used.
See  https://colinpaice.blog/tag/activity-trace/